# A couple of redirects after clicking in a link, what are they after?

Tags: virus, url-redirection

I got an mass email from an friend containing only this link (made not clicable on purpose):

```
http://www.casadelapiedra.com/components/com_content/id876757355.php
```

I imagine she is got some kind of virus, but since I'm curious and not very careful I clicked on.

The PHP that loaded redirected me to another site.

PHP page:

`<h1>
You are here because one of your friends <br> have invited you.<br>
Page loading, please wait....
</h1>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://newsmarketgenonline10go.eu/?12/2">`

That other site in turn gave a '302 moved temporarily' and redirected me to Google.

Whois doesn't reveal anything about the domain, dig on the MX shows that they use a dynamic DNS. Didn't get any extra info on the A record, besides that is from Latvia:  ns1.altnet.lv. admin.altnet.lv

What could them be after? Confirming email addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first link uses a redirect webpage that is detected by many antivirus products as:

- Sophos: **Troj/Redir-O**
- Microsoft: **Trojan:HTML/BlacoleRef.A**
- Kaspersky: **Trojan.HTML.Redirector.an**
- AntiVir: **HTML/FriendLoad.A**

The text `<h1> You are here because one of your friends <br> have invited you.<br> Page loading, please wait....` is the thing that is being detected so it was probably used  before in a malware or spam campaign to redirect to different websites.

An analysis of an older but similar redirector is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Trojan%3aHTML/Redirector.CH).

> [...] will redirect you to the following website that masquerades as a
>   **CNBC website** article,
>   For example:
>
> - marketnewsonline10.com
> - marketnewsonline11.com
> - marketnewsnext7online.com

The site it redirect to, `http://newsmarketgenonline10go.eu` is detected by Websense ThreatSeeker as a **phishing site**.

Other similar domains used in the same campaign are also detected as phishing:

- Phishtank:    **Phishing site**
- Comodo Site Inspector:    **Phishing site**
- Websense ThreatSeeker:    **Phishing site**

This looks to me like an abandoned phishing campaign.